# twitter いいねボタンの処理

Tags: ios, twitter

twitterのいいねボタンの通信処理はどのように実装していますでしょうか？
連続でタップしても、アニメーションとともに、いいねのボタンのカウントも増減しています。
どのタイミングで、サーバーやりとりしているのか、連続タップごとに通信が走っていることもないと思いますので、どなたかご教授願います。